# Meaning of Vector with Matrix Elements

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

What is the meaning of a vector with matrix variables as it’s elements? For example:

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        \mathbf I \\
        \mathbf P
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: It's just a shorter notation of a matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matrix made up of the two matrices $I$ and $P$. So

$$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
I\\
P\end{array}
\right) = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
i_{11} & i_{12}&\dots&i_{1n}\\
i_{21} & i_{22}&\dots&i_{2n}\\
\vdots & \vdots &\ddots & \vdots\\
i_{m1} & i_{m2}&\dots&i_{mn}\\
p_{11} & p_{12}&\dots&p_{1n}\\
p_{21} & p_{22}&\dots&p_{2n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
p_{k1} & p_{k2}&\dots&p_{kn}\\
\end{array}
\right).$$

Comment: That's exactly the definition that I was looking for! I have a related follow-up question that I'll ask in a different post regarding the transpose of a concatenated matrix with this notation type.